# how to display the data that is not duplicate using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, duplicates

imagine I have two tables.the first is Film and the second is Store

the store table has a store_id column and the value inside store_id are 1 and 2. the Film table has title_name of the movies.

my question is to join the two tables and display the name of the movie in store 1 only .. if the movie that in store 1 is also in store 2 then must not display it in store 1

example

if the movie (the mist) is in store 1 and not in store 2  then display it
but the movie (the mist is in store 1 and in store 2 then not display it

here the actual question with clarification and if possible to have the query in postgresql

List the top 100 movies rented (by number of times they were rented) from store1 that are not in top 100 movies rented from store2. Your query must generate a single column TITLE containing the list of movies that meet the given conditions.

CLARIFICATION:

Select the top 100 movies from Store 1 and REMOVE the movies that are also in store 2, leaving a result of less than 100. You must additional order both lists alphabetically to ensure that you always get the same result. The order of the final result is irrelevant.

Comment: Hints - EXCEPT or NOT EXISTS or NOT IN. And do your homework. You won't learn if you ask others to give you answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 st1.title_name
FROM (store1 st1 ORDER BY st1.nr_times_rented DESC)
EXCEPT 
SELECT TOP 100 st2.title_name 
FROM (store2 st2 
ORDER BY nr_times_rented DESC)
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 100 st1.title_name
FROM store1 st1
WHERE s1.title_name NOT IN (SELECT TOP 100 st2.title_name 
                              FROM store2 st2 
                             ORDER BY nr_times_rented DESC)
ORDER BY st1.nr_times_rented DESC
```

Read up on [EXCEPT here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)